# Why are demons and other fallen angels loyal to the devil according to the Bible?

Tags: satan, demons

I have two questions in one for this: From Apocryphal and Non Apocryphal texts. We see that different sets of angels sinned.

*1* Lucifer and his angels

*2* Watchers before the flood(producing the pre flood Nephs).

*3* Sons of God after the flood(producing the post flood Nephs)

furthermore we discover that demons are Nephillim souls disembodied as punishment against the watchers(as mentioned in the book of enoch) and that the devil and his angels are beneath our feets in hell.

**1** Why do these all answer to the devil? / why do demons do the bidding of the devil according to scriptures?

**2** Why is azazel bound while the devil is free? Is the devil not the father of sin(Why isn't he bound instead)?

Comment: How do we know that the other Demons are loyal to Satan. They do not even love themselves. How can they serve faithfully the Chief Devil of the Abyss. Could it be a preference in lieu of loyalty?

Comment: Obedience being a virtue, they must of necessity being compelled by God to do the bidding of Satan, for there is not a note of virtue in Hell. That, or they risk further punishment by Satan or 'higher ups' for not doing their bidding.

Comment: There is no evidence of sons of G-d repeating Genesis 6 after the flood. It is inferred due to the descendants of Nephilim or those who still have Nephilim DNA. However there are other means that the seed of the sons of G-d crosses the flood. The one you mention is the least likely, the most likely is through one or more of Noah’s daughters in law.

Comment: Are you an Ethiopian Christian because they are the only ones to include the book of Enoch in the canon of the Bible. As such much of what you are asking is not from the Bible but the book of Enoch.

Answer (score 1):

> Disclaimer: I do not believe an iota in the Apocryphal writings and
>   thus do not know about the pre-flood, post-flood ideas of fall of
>   heavenly beings (? not sure) talked about in the question. But
>   regarding the fall of Lucifer and the angels who joined him in heaven,
>   I would like to give an answer

You were correct in asserting the angels of Satan are united in working against God's kingdom, for Jesus Himself clarified this:

> “And Jesus knew their thoughts, and said unto them, Every kingdom divided against itself is brought to desolation; and every city or house divided against itself shall not stand: And if Satan cast out Satan, he is divided against himself; how shall then his kingdom stand?” (Matthew 12:25–26, KJV 1900)

But, how is this unity achieved? Why do they obey Satan?

1. Might is right - this is the principle of the kingdom of Satan where Love does not exist. Before fall Lucifer stood next to God. He veiled the glory of God. Notice in the following verse concerning Lucifer it is said that he is the anointed cherub that covers - to understand this, we need to look at the ark of the covenant, where the presence of God - The Shekinah, was covered by 2 cherubs. This was the position of Lucifer in heaven.

   > “Thou art the anointed cherub that covereth; and I have set thee so: thou wast upon the holy mountain of God; thou hast walked up and down in the midst of the stones of fire.” (Ezekiel 28:14, KJV 1900)

It stands to reason that he was one of the most highly exalted beings, continually being right next to God - and we can follow this reasoning to assume that he was one of the most powerful creatures created by God. Talking about the might of Satan, Daniel 10 says that Gabriel could not contend with "the prince of the kingdom of Persia" - a name used for Satan - and that the Arch Angel Michael, who prevailed over Lucifer in heaven (Revelation 12:7) had to come down to fight him so that Daniel could receive an answer to his prayer.

2. Having chosen the side of Satan, the other angels are to partake of the same punishment as their leader - thus they partly co-operate with him in opposing God's kingdom. They do everything in their power to discomfit and defeat God in their purposes.

   > “And the angels which kept not their first estate, but left their own habitation, he hath reserved in everlasting chains under darkness unto the judgment of the great day.” (Jude 6, KJV 1900)

As the wisest among them is Satan, they naturally follow his plan in this battle

Talking about Satan's wisdom, the Bible says:

> “Son of man, take up a lamentation upon the king of Tyrus, and say unto him, Thus saith the Lord GOD; Thou sealest up the sum, full of wisdom, and perfect in beauty.” (Ezekiel 28:12, KJV 1900)

Comment: The Prince of Persia reference is not obvious to mean satan but it is more likely to mean a principality of which there are many and chapter 11 seems to suggest that Persia had four in total because historically more than four kings ruled over the Persian empire. It is also these principslities that gave their power to satan when he says, all these kingdom have been given to me during the temptation of Jesus in the wilderness.

Comment: The prince of Persia of Daniel 10 is not necessarily the same as Daniel 11. Daniel 11 deals with the future history of the kingdom of Persia. Daniel 10 talks about the reason why Daniel's prayer was not answered - this being the prince of Persia withstood Gabriel preventing Gabriel from answering Daniel's prayer. Is it possible for a frail human to withstand an angel? In the story of Hezekiah 180000 men were slain in one night by an angel. It is impossible for a man to stop an angel - this brings us to the conclusion that the "Prince of Persia" is an angel in chapter 10 of Daniel

Comment: I would agree with that actually. I went back afterwards to read the whole of chapter 11 several times in multiple languages and I was not able to make sense of it as being an elohim like in chapter 10. I’m leaving it on the table because I’m not able to devote time to it right now but from the little time I did accord it, it doesn’t jive.  Now as for an “angel” I agree chapter 10 is an elohim  (Psalm 82 and Deu 32:8 LXX and DSS), but I don’t know that you could say with certainty it was satan when there are many elohim and satan being just one of them.